# Transpose list rows into a dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply, transpose

Suppose this is my list structure

```
lst=list(structure(c("level1", "level2", "level4", "level5","18", "abc", "pqr", "lmn"),
         .Dim = c(4L, 2L)), 
     structure(c("level1", "level2", "level3", "level5", "level6", "20", "xyz", "hive", "foo", "bar"), 
        .Dim = c(5L, 2L)),
     structure(c("level1", "level3", "level4", "level5","level6", "22", "dark", "yellow","foobar", "blue"), 
        .Dim = c(5L, 2L)),
     structure(c("level1", "level2", "level3", "level5","level6","level7","24", "dvd", "dxs","glass", "while","though"), 
     .Dim = c(6L, 2L))
     )
```

Expecting O/P something like this

```
     level1 level2  level3  level4  level5  level6  level7
1)     18       abc     NA      pqr     lmn     NA      NA
2)     20       xyz     hive    NA      foo     bar     NA
3)     22       NA      dark    yellow  foobar  blue    NA
4)     24       dvd     dxs     NA      glass   while   though
```

The first column from all list should be transposed and accordingly, corresponding data should get looked up to their rows.

Trying to do transpose of all rows to column itself giving error

```
 unique(t(list_temp[[c(1,2)]][,1]))
ERROR:Error in list_temp[[c(1, 2)]][, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Also tried with

```
apply(list_temp,1,function(x){list_temp[[x]][,1]})
```

But gave me

```
Error in apply(list_temp, 1, function(x) { : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Any suggestion on how should it be done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two approaches:

**1) using the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)-package**

With:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(rbindlist(lapply(lst, as.data.table), idcol = 'id'),
      id ~ V1, value.var = 'V2')[, id := NULL][]
```

you get:

> ```
>    level1 level2 level3 level4 level5 level6 level7
> 1:     18    abc     NA    pqr    lmn     NA     NA
> 2:     20    xyz   hive     NA    foo    bar     NA
> 3:     22     NA   dark yellow foobar   blue     NA
> 4:     24    dvd    dxs     NA  glass  while though
> ```

**2) using base R**

With:

```
reshape(transform(do.call(rbind.data.frame, lst),
                  r = rep(seq_along(lst), lengths(lst)/2)),
        idvar = 'r', timevar = 'V1', direction = 'wide')[,-1]
```

you get:

> ```
>    V2.level1 V2.level2 V2.level4 V2.level5 V2.level3 V2.level6 V2.level7
> 1         18       abc       pqr       lmn      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>
> 5         20       xyz      <NA>       foo      hive       bar      <NA>
> 10        22      <NA>    yellow    foobar      dark      blue      <NA>
> 15        24       dvd      <NA>     glass       dxs     while    though
> ```

Comment: That was so clean and elegant...+1 for rbindlist..Thanks for your time and effort!!!

Comment: I think there is some bug in your code ..if I have 4 list records instead of 2 then it doesn't give right output.

Comment: @deepesh Could you include(add) an example that reproduces your problem in your question?

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: @deepesh It appears to be working for me as far as I can see, see also the updated answer for the new data. Could you explain what is wrong with the output?

Comment: 1st record of list doesn't have "level7" column, but your code populates all column records for 1st record of a list..please see the Expected O/P...it gives the format in which O/P is expected.

Comment: @deepesh Thx, I now see what went wrong. I've updated the answer.

Comment: great..That's working perfectly fine now...Much Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is another idea using `Reduce` to merge the data frames, then transpose and do some cleaning, i.e.

```
m1 <- t(Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = 'V1', all = TRUE), lapply(lst, as.data.frame)))
colnames(m1) <- m1[1,]
row.names(m1) <- NULL
final_d <- as.data.frame(m1[-1,], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

which gives,

> ```
>    level1 level2 level4 level5 level3 level6 level7
> 1     18    abc    pqr    lmn   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
> 2     20    xyz   <NA>    foo   hive    bar   <NA>
> 3     22   <NA> yellow foobar   dark   blue   <NA>
> 4     24    dvd   <NA>  glass    dxs  while though
> ```

Comment: that's also a good approach to go with..Thanks for your time and effort!!!